# Concordion Markdown vs Concordion HTML

Tags: html, markdown, specifications, concordion

According to the Concordion Getting Started guide:

> Note: Since v2.0, Concordion also supports Markdown specifications,
>   which are easier to read and write than HTML. However, HTML provides a
>   richer language, so may be preferred for complex scenarios.

What can you do in HTML in a Concordion SPE that you cannot do in Markdown?

Answer (score 0):

From the Concordion syntax point of view, one is [handling unusual sentence structures](https://concordion.org/instrumenting/java/markdown/#handling-unusual-sentence-structures). Another is [using the Collapse Extension](https://github.com/concordion/concordion/issues/218#issuecomment-244593522) with Markdown.

Note that we are in the process of [updating our Markdown parser](https://github.com/concordion/concordion/pull/272) from Pegdown to Flexmark, which may open up opportunities to do a bit more in Markdown.